# Flutter date picker validation

Tags: flutter, datepicker

How to clear selected dob using date picker from text field after submission in flutter?

I validate it return null. But it does not work
What can i do?

Comment: if you're using form, you can do form.clear(). Please add some code for any question.

Comment: please shoe the code what you have done

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
final dateController = TextEditingController();
```

set date in controller for example 
`dateController.text = "21-12-2021";`

```
 TextField(
                controller: dateController,   
                
            //  controller: dateController,
            autofocus: false,
            onChanged: (value) {},
          )
```

get date value from controller

```
  String date =  dateController.text;
```

after submission date just clear dateController.
set date Picker to current date like below..

```
dateController.clear() //clear text field 

final DateTime pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: initialDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2021, 12),
      lastDate: DateTime(3000),
    );
```